# How to switch between windows with VB?

Tags: vba, ms-word, window

I want to use vba to switch between window, so I use the "switch windows" functions and record it with macro. It works fine to click the button manually, but when I use the recorded vb code, it don't work at all. What can be the problem?

the code is like:

```
Windows(2).Activate
```

I have depleted searching for methods, but many solutions provided by the search result don't work at all...

the codes that don't work:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Next.Activate
```

or

```
Sub AcivateNextDocumentWindow()
  On Error GoTo ProcessError

  If Windows.Count > 1 Then
    Dim objWindow As Window

    Set objWindow = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Next
    objWindow.Activate
  End If
  Exit Sub

ProcessError:
  Windows(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue.  How are you calling the macro?  I have two windows, each with a different workbook.  Each workbook has the same 3 line macro `Sub test()`, `Application.Windows(2).Activate`, `End Sub`.  Calling the macro from either workbook activates the other.  It works via a button on the worksheet and also selecting the drop-down in the macro window on the developer tab.  It does not work if called from the visual basic editor.  Win10 Pro/Office 365 ProPlus

Comment: It will help us help you if you describe what the purpose is of "switching windows". I would guess that you're trying to perform actions between two documents, such as copying/moving content. There are very efficient ways that can be done, that do not require activating windows. If you could use the [edit] link below the question to add information about what you need to accomplish we might be able to provide useful information...

Comment: well, I found my problem ended up that open multiple views into one document, and thus the code does not work at all. thank you for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue might be due to the difference between documents and windows. Windows can be multiple "views" into one document (you'll see a name like Document1:1, Document 1:2, etc) or into multiple, different documents. If you're running the macro from a code within a specific document, you might get issues. Suggest you add the code into the normal template. In addition to some code to cycle through the windows, I've included some debug code for you. Cheers.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DocumentsAndWindows()

    Dim vDocument As Document
    Dim vWindow As Window

    Debug.Print "Number of Documents.......: " & Application.Documents.Count
    For Each vDocument In Application.Documents
        Debug.Print "   Document...............:" & vDocument.Name
    Next
    Debug.Print

    Debug.Print "Number of Windows.........: " & Application.Windows.Count
    For Each vWindow In Application.Windows
        Debug.Print "   Window.................: " & vWindow.Index & " - " & vWindow.Document.Name
    Next
    Debug.Print "   Current Window.........: " & Application.ActiveWindow.WindowNumber
    Debug.Print

End Sub

Public Sub CycleWindows()

    If Application.ActiveWindow.Index < Application.Windows.Count Then
        Application.Windows(Application.ActiveWindow.Index + 1).Activate
    Else
        Application.Windows(1).Activate
    End If

    Debug.Print "Current Window is.........: " & Application.ActiveWindow.Index
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the debug code! it ends up that its the problem of opening multiple views into a window and for some strange reasons these windows become invisible. I fixed it just by restart the program itself:)